# How do I allow outgoing connections from a service in UFW?

Tags: apache-2.2, ufw

Hey I am using Apache server to power my Python-Flask application. It uses urllib2 which makes outgoing connections requests which are blocked by UFW.

How do I allow only Apache to make outgoing connections requests and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

To allow outgoing traffic for a port you open it like this:

```
# Allow out for port 80
sudo ufw allow out 80
```

Further details on [the ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall#Method_2_:_UFW)